# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am writing a couple of interfaces for tree data structure. I am getting 
`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E` compilation error.

Here is my interface hierarchy:

```
package com.mohit.dsa.global.position;

/**
 * @author mohitkum
 */
public interface Position<E> {
    public E getElement() throws IllegalStateException;
}
```

--

```
package com.mohit.dsa.tree;

import com.mohit.dsa.global.position.Position;

public interface Tree<E> extends Iterable<E> {
    Position<E> root;//compilation error for E
}
```

It will be great if someone can explain the cause of this error.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a field in an interface, it is public static final. So `Position root;` (even without generics) is invalid in an interface. Further lets assume you are initializing the final field root and say your Tree interface is implemented as:

```
class A1 implements Tree<A>

class B1 implements Tree<B>
```

This would become a problem right? Since this would translate to:

`Position<A>` root in one case 
`Position<B>` root in another case

but your field is final so this cant work.

The below thread is related:
[Java - An interface that has static field pointing to class name of its sub class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577538/java-an-interface-that-has-static-field-pointing-to-class-name-of-its-sub-clas)